# New virtual function in middle class of inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class top {
    public:
        virtual void foo(void) {cout << "I am top foo\n";}
};
class middle : public top {
    public:
        virtual void foo(void) {cout << "I am middle foo\n";}
        virtual void bar(void) {cout << "I am middle bar\n";}
};
class lower : public middle {
    public:
        virtual void foo(void) {cout << "I am lower foo\n";}
        virtual void bar(void) {cout << "I am lower bar\n";}
};
int main() {
    top *t = new top();
    middle *m = new middle();
    lower *l;
    t = m;
    t->foo(); // works fine
    t = l;
    t->foo(); // causes segmentation fault/ undefined behavior
    l->foo(); // works fine if above is commented

    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that similar queries have been answered here but I want to visualize this from vtable layout point of view. Is invoking intermediate class virtual function call not allowed if their vtable layout differ? Here I see that virtual bar() is defined middle class onwards. How would the vtable layouts of each class look like?

Comment: `l` is an uninitialized pointer, of course it has undefined behaviour. Did you mean to write something else?

Comment: Oh..I see I wanted to create scenario where vtable memory layouts of classes in inheritance hierarchy differ. Seeing this error, I had thought that I've created one, my bad. But is it allowed to have new virtual functions defined in middle level classes and use them?

Comment: Yes of course it is. If it wasn't allowed then you'd get a compile-time error, not undefined behaviour. C++ is complicated, but not designed by evil lunatics.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `t` to `l`, when `l` is uninitialized.

Comment: And dereferencing `l` directly as well.